# A simple form application

Tags: pdf, ms-office

I am here for a suggestion. I want to build a simple application that contains some forms (3 to 4). In each form people can input and then at the last form the result will be auto calculated based on the user input. The users of this application are normal people.

Actually it would be better if the application could be built as a simple pdf file. Since the auto calculated fields require only addition or subtraction operations, is it possible to make such pdf files? If yes then which software should I use?
Again nowadays people are quite familiar about Microsoft office. The users normally use Word, Excel and power point. So, I am thinking of Excel. Is it a good Idea?

Restrictions: People cannot change the underlying formulas of the forms. Is it possible in pdf or excel?

Waiting for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am getting from your question , If you know .net then i would suggest you to go for Winform with sqllite database. This will ease you UI design time nd coding time too. Since .net exe's are compiled so , your unerlying formula will be hidden and secure. Also data will be secure in db. After all inputs you can query and display output. Whereasif you opt Adobe Pdf or Excel then either you have to go for AIR Programming or VBA using Excel which more complex than normal database programming in .net

Comment: Hey Amit,
I know .net a little. But I never made an installer that contains database application. Do the users have to install the database components? Can you provide me some links that might help?

Thanks

Comment: . net has built in deployment support. You need not to know more. Google using creating Setup in .net , you will com across 1000's of documents. Choose which ever you found easy. Also while craeting a new project in .net will automatically add all application references. But database and custome files you need to specify

Answer (score 0):

I think [InfoPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_InfoPath) is what you are looking for.